# Bundle install error with "omniauth-oauth2"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, bundle, bundler, omniauth

Running `bundle install` I get the following error (full trace: http://pastebin.com/Vp4nHc2p):

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "omniauth-oauth2":
  In Gemfile:
    omniauth-facebook (~> 1.2.0) ruby depends on
      omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.0.0) ruby

    omniauth-github (~> 1.0.1) ruby depends on
      omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.1)
```

To see my Gemfile: http://pastebin.com/vMcHDHa8

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you probably need to install omniauth facebook and github versions which accept the same version of omniauth-oath2 ..

It looks like you need to update both gems... then they will both accept omniauth-oath2 version 1.1

Check out the dependencies on:

https://rubygems.org/gems/omniauth-facebook

https://rubygems.org/gems/omniauth-github

Just replace the links for omniauth-github and facebook gems in your gemfile with:

```
gem "omniauth-github", "~> 1.0.3"
gem "omniauth-facebook", "~> 1.4.1"
```

Then run `bundle update omniauth-gihub` and then `bundle update omniauth-facebook`

You should then be ok.

NOTE: I am assuming 1.1 and 1.1.0 are the same version, if not you may need to consult rubygems to find 3 compatible gems by reading out the dependencies for omniauth-facebook and github