# Rails: Bundle cannot resolve dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, omniauth, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using various omniauth gems and after I added PayPal I get this error when running `bundle` or `bundle update`:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "omniauth-oauth2":
  In Gemfile:
omniauth-dribbble (~> 0.0.1) x86-mingw32 was resolved to 0.0.1, which
depends on
      omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.1) x86-mingw32

omniauth-dribbble (~> 0.0.1) x86-mingw32 was resolved to 0.0.1, which
depends on
      omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.1) x86-mingw32

omniauth-facebook (~> 4.0) x86-mingw32 was resolved to 4.0.0, which depends
on
      omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.2) x86-mingw32

omniauth-google-oauth2 (~> 0.4.1) x86-mingw32 was resolved to 0.4.1, which
depends on
      omniauth-oauth2 (>= 1.3.1) x86-mingw32

    omniauth-paypal (~> 1.2) x86-mingw32 was resolved to 1.2, which depends on
      omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.1.0) x86-mingw32
```

Is there a way to circumvent this and still use the Omniauth PayPal Gem?

**EDIT:**

The PayPal Gem does conflict with the Google Omniauth solution. I cannot have them both. Why?

Comment: Could be the same as the following? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839972/bundle-install-error-with-omniauth-oauth2

Comment: I kinda felt this way too, but I looked at the dependencies and they should be all good ...

Comment: @pschneider - Take a look at the updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have them both because paypal depends on omniauth 1.1 and google-oath2 depends on omniauth 1.3. You should wait until paypal uses omniauth 1.3.

Comment: Or fork either of the two gems and update its dependencies.

Comment: Yes that's also possible.

Comment: And why do the other gems work with each other when facebook depends on 1.2?

Comment: Because facebook depends on all versions after 1.2 until 2.0.

Comment: see http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#pessimistic-version-constraint

Comment: Thank you! How can include a forked and edited repository in my gemfile?

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you are using the more recent version of the gems and bundle update.  If this does not work.

Then you can fork the gems.  Change the dependency for "omniauth-oauth2" and refer to your forked gems.  This way both gems refer to the same dependent gem.